# jquery clear/reset $(this).html() so it can be used again

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
    $('#foo').click(function () {

       var xyz = $('#foo2').val().length;

    if(xyz < 1) {

        $('#msg').html('<div id="error">error</div>').delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);

    } else ......
```

and i'm having issues with this line:

```
$('#msg').html('<div id="error">error</div>').delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
```

It shows an error message if xyz is 0 but the problem is it only works once and I need it to work multiple times so if on click 2nd, 3rd, 4th time etc it pops back up, is there a way to clear/reset .html() so it can be used again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to clear/reset it. all you need to do is show it.

```
$('#msg').html('<div id="error">error</div>').show().delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
```

`.html()` uses `.empty()` internally before it uses `innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to clear/reset .html()

Yes, there is. Use [**.empty()**](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Comment: I tend to doubt that it's going to fix Anna's problem though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#msg').html('<div id="error">error</div>').delay(3000).fadeOut(1000, function(){
    $(this).empty()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not `.html()` it's `.fadeOut()` You fade the div out, now it's hidden. (`display:none;`). You need to show it again to fade it out.

You can clear it's content by calling [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) and then show it again after you hide the message. Or you can just show it before calling your line to delay/fade.

```
$('#foo').html('<div id="error">error</div>').show().delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsbin.com/oxaqar/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#msg').empty().html('<div id="error">error</div>').show().fadeOut(1000);
```